# Removing JQuery dependency from Angular app

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In the process of removing JQuery dependency from our Angular project.  Most of the work to remove JQuery has been done.

Currently I'm just doing a global find on '`$.`' to identify those sections of code that still utilize JQuery.

Is there something else I should be searching for?

Comment: `jQuery`.......

Comment: jQuery... some people don't use the alias `$`

Comment: Don't jslint/jshint help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @tushar and @taxicala for suggesting I also search for jQuery (in case the alias is not used).

In addition to searching for `'$.'` and `'jQuery'`, we've also found reliance on jQuery from `element` in our directives.

From the [Angular `element` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): "If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite.”"

So to summarize...

1. search for `$.`
2. search for `jQuery`
3. search for uses of `element` that rely on jQuery and not just [jqlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Thanks again to those who commented!